How to use SUBSTITUTE inside a COUNTIFS?
I would like to automatically count the of times a certain item is mentioned in a list. Unfortunately, the list contains variant spelling of the item, which may or may not contain dashes and/or spacebars. Similarly, the name of the item may also contain similar variations. Therefore I want to apply SUBSTITUTE to replace all spaces and dashes with nothing, and compare the results. Having a separate column is impractical.
So I want something like this, and tried this and a couple of variations
=LET(

teamName, $A$105,
teamNameRange, $B$3:$B$102,
itemNameRange, $J$3:$J$102,
itemName, A108

sum, COUNTIFS(teamNameRange, teamName, SUBSTITUTE(itemNameRange,"-",""), SUBSTITUTE(itemName,"-","")),

sum
)

but of course that doesn't work, likely because SUBSTITUTE does not naturally produce an array or something like that.
What is the proper way to do it?

You will need MAP() or MMULT() function here with SUM() function. COUNTIFS() will not work with arrays.

COUNTIFS() is logical and. the equivalent is *, the multiplication operator. you can replace your COUNTIFS() with SUM((teamNameRange=teamName)*(SUBSTITUTE(itemNameRange,"-","")=SUBSTITUTE(itemName,"-","")))

The "natural" way to do it would be
=LET(
    teamName, $A$105,
    teamNameRange, $B$3:$B$102,
    itemNameRange, $J$3:$J$102,
    itemName, A108,
    sum, SUM((teamNameRange = teamName) * (SUBSTITUTE(itemNameRange, "-", "") = SUBSTITUTE(itemName, "-", ""))),
    sum
)

Below (range1 = x) * (range2 = y) returns 1 if both teamName and itemName are found in the given row, returns zero otherwise.
=(teamNameRange = teamName) * (SUBSTITUTE(itemNameRange, "-", "") = SUBSTITUTE(itemName, "-", ""))
